# argument/value in php link

Tags: php, url, parameter-passing

I got 2 .php pages:

1. `index.php` : the main page with 4 pictures (1 by sensor)
2. `function.php` : display temperature from a sensor and send it with the sensor id to a database

I want to click on the sensor's pic and be redirected to a display page (`function.php`).

In `index.php`, I will have probably:

```
< a href="funtion.php?1">pic1.jpg< /a>" <br>
< a href="funtion.php?2">pic2.jpg< /a>" <br>
< a href="funtion.php?3">pic3.jpg< /a>" <br>
< a href="funtion.php?4">pic4.jpg< /a>" <br>
```

In my `function.php` page, I want to store the number after `?` as a variable (`$id`).
In this page I will send the variable $id to collect the temperature, display id & temp and store id & temp to database.

My Question is:
How can I collect the number in the url and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP this is simple.

I have the URL

```
<a href="function.php?myparameter=12345">Link here</a>
```

all I have to is the following (in the target page - function.php) to retrieve the named url URL parameter.

```
if (isset($_GET['myparameter'])) {
       $myVariableName =  $_GET['myparameter'];
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters with [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Imagine you've a link like:

```
<a href="some_script.php?pic_number=1">pic1.jpg</a>
```

you can retrieve the `pic_number` value using:

```
<?php
if(isset( $_GET['pic_number']))
{
    $pic_number = $_GET['pic_number'];
    # do something with $pic_number
}
```